# VM or Flow-Ref for eCommerce system

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am developing a mule application where I have to take orders from One system System-1 & have to send it to the another system say System-2 through soap (which actually takes care of creation of orders, invoices etc) & the response from System-2 is routed back to system-1 with success or failure response. Now what approach should be the best, will a VM be the best approach for referencing purpose or a flow reference ? The number of orders coming could be like 100 per hour. Also for both cases what should be the ideal worker size ?

Answer (score 0):

If the system 2 is to be called SOAP web service, you should be using web service consumer component or an http requester component.

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand the difference between flowref and vm.

Both flowref and vm are used to call another flow within the mule application.

Major difference between both is vm uses in-memory queue to refer to other flow and it creates a transport barrier, hence flow variable and inbound properties wont be propagated across, hence use of vm component should be considered only of it creating a transport barrier is necessary.

If thats(creating transport barrier) not the requirement, usage of flow ref is recommended.